# Swift Public protocols with Internal functions and properties

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, access-modifiers, swift-protocols

I am wondering what the best practice is when I want some functions to be public and some to me internal when working with protocols.
I am writing an [AudioManager](https://github.com/Sajjon/SwiftAudioManager) in **Swift 3** wrapping `AVPlayer` as a framework.
 I want some methods to be public, so that e.g. a ViewController making use of the AudioManager can access some methods, but some methods would not be exposed outside the framework
 -> i.e. having the access modifier `internal` instead of `public`.
 I am writing the framework with protocol driven design, almost every part should have a protocol.
So protocols are talking to protocols within the framework.
 E.g. the main class - `AudioManager` - has an `AudioPlayer`, and should be able to call some `internal` functions on it,
 e.g. `pause(reason:)` but that method should be `internal` and not exposed outside the framework.
Here is an example.

```
internal enum PauseReason {
    case byUser
    case routeChange
}

// Compilation error: `Public protocol cannot refine an internal protocol`
public protocol AudioPlayerProtocol: InternalAudioPlayerProtocol { 
   func pause() // I want 
}

internal protocol InternalAudioPlayerProtocol {
    func pause(reason: PauseReason) // Should only be accessible within the framework
}

public class AudioPlayer: AudioPlayerProtocol {
    public func pause() {
        pause(reason: .byUser)
    }

    // This would probably not compile because it is inside a public class...
    internal func pause(reason: PauseReason) { //I want this to be internal
        // save reason and to stuff with it later on
    }
}

public protocol AudioManagerProtocol {
    var audioPlayer: AudioPlayerProtocol { get }
}

public class AudioManager: AudioManagerProtocol {
    public let audioPlayer: AudioPlayerProtocol

    init() {
        audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleRouteChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVAudioSessionRouteChange, object: nil)
    }

    func handleRouteChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let reasonRaw = userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? NSNumber,
        let reason = AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason(rawValue: reasonRaw.uintValue)
        else { print("what could not get route change") }
        switch reason {
        case .oldDeviceUnavailable:
            pauseBecauseOfRouteChange()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

private extension AudioManager {
    func pauseBecauseOfRouteChange() {
        audioPlayer.pause(reason: .routeChange)
    }
}

// Outside of Audio framework
class PlayerViewController: UIViewController {
    fileprivate let audioManager: AudioManagerProtocol 
    @IBAction didPressPauseButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // I want the `user of the Audio framwwork` (in this case a ViewController)
        // to only be able to `see` `pause()` and not `pause(reason:)` 
        audioManager.audioPlayer.pause()
    }
}
```

**I know I can get it to work by changing the method `pauseBecauseOfRouteChange` to look like this:**

```
func pauseBecauseOfRouteChange() {
    guard let internalPlayer = audioPlayer as? InternalAudioPlayerProtocol else { return }
    internalPlayer.pause(reason: .routeChange)
}
```

**But I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution?**
 Something like marking that the `AudioPlayerProtocol` refines the `InternalAudioPlayerProtocol`...

Or how do you fellow programmers do it?
The framework is more beautiful if it does not expose methods and variables that are intended for internal use!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no more elegant solution to this, at least when considering protocols, and here is why:

Imagine a scenario that someone using your framework wants to write an extension for the `AudioPlayerProtocol`, how then `pause(reason:)` method can be implemented if it's internal?

You can achieve it by just subclassing and this code actually will compile:

```
public class AudioPlayer: AudioPlayerProtocol {
    public func pause() {
        pause(reason: .byUser)
    }

    internal func pause(reason: PauseReason) {
    }
}
```

With protocols this is not the case, because you simply cannot guarantee implementation of internal function if someone with public access level wants to use your mixed public/internal protocol.

Answer (score 2):

How about if you split your protocol into internal and public and then let the public implementation class delegate to an internal implementation. Like so

```
internal protocol InternalAudioPlayerProtocol {
    func pause(reason: PauseReason) 
}

public protocol AudioPlayerProtocol {
    func pause()
}

internal class InternalAudioPlayer: InternalAudioPlayerProtocol {
    internal func pause(reason: PauseReason) { 
    }
}

public class AudioPlayer: AudioPlayerProtocol  {
    internal var base: InternalAudioPlayerProtocol

    internal init(base: InternalAudioPlayerProtocol) {
        self.base = base
    }

    public func pause() {
        base.pause(reason: .byUser)
    }
}

public protocol AudioManagerProtocol {
    var audioPlayer: AudioPlayerProtocol { get }
}

public class AudioManager: AudioManagerProtocol {
    internal let base = InternalAudioPlayer()
    public let audioPlayer: AudioPlayerProtocol

    public init() {
        audioPlayer = AudioPlayer(base: base)
    }

    internal func handleSomeNotification() {            
        pauseBecauseOfRouteChange() //amongst other things
    }

    internal func pauseBecauseOfRouteChange() {
        base.pause(reason: .routeChange)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an old topic but what one can do is actually the opposite. 
Instead of publicProtocol extending internalProtocol have internalProtocol extending publicProtocol.

```
public protocol AudioPlayerProtocol { 
   func pause() // I want 
}

internal protocol InternalAudioPlayerProtocol: AudioPlayerProtocol {
    func pause(reason: PauseReason) // Should only be accessible within the framework
}

public class AudioPlayer: InternalAudioPlayerProtocol {
    public func pause() {
        pause(reason: .byUser)
    }

    internal func pause(reason: PauseReason) { 
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Then in the manager

```
public class AudioManager: AudioManagerProtocol {
    public let audioPlayer: AudioPlayerProtocol
    private let intAudioPlayer: InternalAudioPlayerProtocol

    init() {
        intAudioPlayer = AudioPlayer()
        audioPlayer = intAudioPlayer
        ...
    }
    ...
    private func pauseBecauseOfRouteChange() {
        intAudioPlayer.pause(reason: .routeChange)
    }
}
```